# Use multiple left joins to set DTO property inside select new linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have the following code inside an MVC 6 (beta8) controller:

```
public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var districtsdetails = from districts in _ctx.District
            select new
            {
                Id = districts.Id,
                CountyFP = districts.County.FIPSCode,
                DirectorName = districts.DirectorName,
                Email = districts.Email,
                EstStudentPop = districts.EstStudentPop,
                Name = districts.Name,
                Phone = districts.Phone,
                Ranking = districts.Ranking,
                RANumber = districts.RANumber,
                SchoolCount = districts.SchoolCount,
                Coop = districts.Coop.Name,
                County = districts.County.Name,

                Distributors = (from district in _ctx.District
                               join districtdistributor in _ctx.DistrictDistributor on district.Id equals districtdistributor.DistrictId
                               into group1
                               from g1 in group1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               join distributor in _ctx.Distributor on g1.DistributorId equals distributor.Id
                               into group2
                               from g2 in group2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               where district.Id == districts.Id
                               select new { g2.Id, g2.Name })
            };

        if (districtsdetails == null)
            return HttpNotFound();


        return new JsonResult(districtsdetails);
    }
```

The problem is in the Distributors property setter.

I have District, DistrictDistributor, and Distributor entities in my context (and matching tables in my db).  There is a many to many relationship between District and Distributor, with DistrictDistributor mapping the many to many relationship between the two.  In my DistrictDetailsDTO I'm attempting to bridge the DistrictDistributor gap so I can just do DistrictDetailsDTO.Distributors ... All this is being serialized to Json as you can see by the JsonResult().

In the Distributor = (...) I am trying to effectively reproduce this SQL:

```
select (...)
from [District] D
left join [DistrictDistributor] DD on
    DD.DistrictId = D.Id
left join [Distributor] Db on
    Db.Id = DD.DistributorId
where id = 57
```

However, in my linq 57 would be districts.Id since I'm returning all Districts.
Please HELP I'm going CRAZY! No matter what I try along these lines produces a:

HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway
The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.

Comment: Do you have navigation properties in your model? Like `Distibutor.Districts` and `District.Distributors`? They can greatly simplify coding your queries, almost always eliminating the need of manual joins - that's the beauty of the EF.

Comment: How would I set up those navigations when the only way to know the relationships between Distributors and Districts is through the DistrictaDistributor table/entity ??

Comment: Ok actually, i think I got that figured out with HasMany() WithMany() but now I'm having the problem of serializing this to JSON... Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I think it could be resolved.

First, your query - the hard way. You don't need left joins here at all. They would be needed if you were producing a joined result set (`SelectMany`), but since that's not the case, you can use the following and let EF do it's magic to make it work:

```
var query =
    from district in _ctx.District.AsNoTracking()
    select new
    {
        Id = district.Id,
        Name = district.Name,
        // the rest of the district related fields
        // ...
        Distributors =
        from dd in _cxt.DistrictDistributor
        where dd.DistrictId == district.Id
        join d in _ctx.Distributor on dd.DistributorId equals d.Id
        select new { d.Id, d.Name }
    };
```

Second - the easy way. One of the cool things of EF is to describe your model with navigation properties and properly configured relationships. This way you can almost forget about manual joins and let EF do whatever is necessary to satisfy your queries. In your case, the proper model would have `District.Distributors` and `Distributor.Districts` navigation properties, and the same result could be achieved with the following simple query:

```
var query =
    from district in _ctx.District.AsNoTracking()
    select new
    {
        Id = district.Id,
        Name = district.Name,
        // the rest of the district related fields
        // ...
        Distributors = district.Distributors.Select(d => new { d.Id, d.Name })
    };
```